# Is there a way to adjust the height and width of an image that is img-responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, screen-size

For context, I use bootstrap that still uses img-responsive instead of img-fluid. I have a big image inside of a div, and since I don't want the image to overflow the div on all screens, I made it img-responsive.
I work on my laptop. When I put my image as img-responsive, the image neither overflows its div on my laptop or phone screen. That is great. However, it is a bit too big for my liking, so I don't make it img-responsive anymore to manually adjust it so that it would be smaller. Of course, on my laptop, the image doesn't overflow because it is smaller, but when I look at it on the smaller screen of my phone, it overflows. I am confused because the image is clearly smaller on my laptop but is bigger on my phone.
How do I fix this? How do I keep the size of the image on my laptop, and not make it overflow on my phone? Here is my HTML:

```css
.project-summary p a, .project-body p a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.project-images {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row project-images">
    <div class="col col-sm-6">
        <div class="project-summary">
            <p>I wasn't willing to go down without a fight, so the week after, I tried again. I realized while watching the brownie video a few more times that the tray Andrew used was much bigger than the one I had, so I halved the recipe. Everything else stayed the same. </p>
            <p>The result was dry brownies with enclosed melted chocolate bits. There was nothing wrong with them. They were much more edible, but the color was still way too dark, and tasted like any other store bought ones. At that point, I was really confused as to why my brownies didn't come out looking as sexy as the video's. I made sure to follow <b>everything</b> down to a tee. Every Saturday afterwards became brownie day until I had perfected my craft.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 padding-0">
        <img height=270 src="./img/extras/brownies/brownie-5.jpg" class="img-responsive" </img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try using media queries?

Comment: media queries are very much a hassle. I believe the reason the image is not overflowing is because it has the img-responsive tag. The div encompasses the screen no matter the size, so since img-responsive allows the image to always fit the div, it will automatically always fit any screen. However, if I don't include the img-responsive tag it messes things up. I want the image to smaller without messing things up.

Comment: use mediaqueries (they are already provided by bootstrap, so just use them). And / Or set a `max-` or `min-` width or height.

Comment: can you add some screen shots to explain the problem and the desired solution?

Comment: @cloned do you know how to set max- of width or height to parent element?

Comment: `.parent-element{max-height: 200px}` ...

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap it is best to use img fluid:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

Check out this link for more help:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/images/#responsive-images

Comment: img-responsive and img-fluid is the same thing, I believe.